# CheckboxListTile in ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

How to put multiple CheckboxListTile inside the ListView widget?
I have already tried to do it but it caught some exceptions.

Comment: Can you provide snippet of what you are trying to do? Show us your not working solutions so we can help you. Or provide log of exceptions. There is nothing we can do right now.

Comment: I'm trying to add checkboxes one after another with the title from the button pressed in ListView so that I can scroll through.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create class CheckBoxListTileModel
(You can put anything in this class and you can define a List As needed)
ex:

```
class CheckBoxListTileModel {
  String title;
  bool isCheck;

  CheckBoxListTileModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.isCheck,
  });

  static List<CheckBoxListTileModel> getList() {
    return <CheckBoxListTileModel>[
      CheckBoxListTileModel(
        title: "Android",
        isCheck: true,
      ),
      CheckBoxListTileModel(
        title: "Flutter",
        isCheck: false,
      ),
      CheckBoxListTileModel(
        title: "IOS",
        isCheck: false,
      ),
      CheckBoxListTileModel(
        title: "PHP",
        isCheck: false,
      ),
      CheckBoxListTileModel(
        title: "Node",
        isCheck: false,
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

create a List is your page class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<CheckBoxListTileModel> checkBoxListTileModel =
      CheckBoxListTileModel.getList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 10,
          vertical: 10,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Choose',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: checkBoxListTileModel.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            checkBoxListTileModel[index].title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          value: checkBoxListTileModel[index].isCheck,
                          onChanged: (bool? val) {
                            setState(() {
                              checkBoxListTileModel[index].isCheck = val!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int i = 0;
                checkBoxListTileModel.forEach((element) {
                  i++;
                  debugPrint('choice$i: ${element.isCheck}');
                  debugPrint('choice$i: ${element.title}\n');
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Get Result'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the button "get result" to see result in console
(Not necessarily put it)

see result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebxJ0.jpg)

see console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8NEP.png)

Answer (score 0):

[multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) this package does just that